# Assembly executable on osx

Tags: macos, assembly, osx-snow-leopard, nasm

I got [nasm](http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.10/macosx/) and I want to compile assembly into an executable. I keep getting the error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file firststart.asm, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

when I try to compile with gcc. I am using gcc that comes with xcode. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, assemble with `nasm -f macho64 firststart.asm`. Then, don't tell gcc about firststart.asm, tell it about firststart.o.

Comment: @FrankKotler So what commands should I use _Specifically_ (if you dont mind)

Comment: Well, after `nasm -f macho64 firststart.asm` probably `gcc -o firststart firststart.o` that's kind of a minimum, you might need more. I'm not familiar with OSX, but I knew a complaint from ld about an .asm file wasn't right. `-f macho32` and tell gcc `-m32` if what you've got is 32-bit code.

Comment: @FrankKotler That did the trick! Mark it as an answer, and I'll put it as correct!